# AttributeError 'myClass' object has no attribute 'myList'

Tags: python, inheritance, attributeerror

I'm running windows 7, using python 2.7.3, and I am getting an inheritance error that I can't figure out why. I've done a good bit of searching but haven't found too much related as of yet.

My problem is that I keep getting a AttributeError when I try to inherit from one class to another. The basic structure I have goes something like this:

```
# pymyClass.py
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self,aList=None):
        if aList is not None:
            myList = aList
        else:
            myList = ['','','','','']

    def reset(self,aList=None):
        if aList is not None:
            myList = aList
        else:
            myList = ['','','','','']
    #other methods operate without issue


# pymySecondClass.py
import pymyClass
class mySecondClass(pymyClass.myClass):
    def __init__(self,aList=None):
        pymyClass.myClass(aList)


# pymyThirdClass.py
import pymySecondClass
class myThirdClass(pymySecondClass.mySecondClass):
    def __init__(self,aList=None):
        pymySecondClass.mySecondClass(aList)

    def useList(self,aList=None):
        self.reset(aList)
        print self.myList


#pymyObj.py
import pymyThirdClass

myObj = pymyThirdClass.myThirdClass(['a','b','c','1','2'])
myObj.useList()
```

...but it errors out when I call instantiate the myThirdClass() and call useList(), saying,

```
AttributeError: 'myThirdClass' object has no attribute 'myList'
```

I actually compiled my example here, and got the same issue, so I'm thinking inheritance doesn't work the way I'm expecting. I've checked the python documentation, but maybe not close enough?  If anyone could help me out here that would be very much appreciated.

I'm thinking I may have to just manually include the field "myList" in the myThirdClass constructor, but that seems incredibly lame.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `__init__` override is not done like this. Read about `super` in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually attach `myList` to the instance anywhere.  To do that (inside a method), you need to do:

```
self.myList = ...
```

rather than just:

```
myList = ...
```

where `self` is the conventional name for the first argument passed to a method.

---

You've also got some problems with what calling the base classes on your derived classes.

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self):
      print "I'm a Foo"

class Bar(Foo):
   def __init__(self):
      print "I'm a Bar"
      #This is one way to call a method with the same name on a base class
      Foo.__init__(self)
```

Some people don't like to do it as `Foo.__init__(self)` -- Those people use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) ([which is Ok too](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) as [long as you know what you're doing](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)).

Comment: Sweet! Well, that fixes my example here, but my bulkier stuff didn't have the same problem. Still, this gives me new things to triple-check. Thanks!

Comment: I'd argue that both `super` and explicit `__init__` calling, warrant deep understanding.

Comment: @rantanplan -- explicit `__init__` calling I find to be pretty intuitive.  You're calling a *function* and passing the proper arguments just like you would to any other function.  It's that easy ...

Comment: Only in simple cases like these. When you have mixins and multiple inheritance things get more complicated. Still, you gave the correct answer.

Comment: @rantanplan -- I hold that it doesn't get any more complicated with multiple inheritance.  You're still calling a *function* on an explicit base class.  As I'm sure you know, `super` calls all the functions on all the base classes implicitly (which is why I don't like it).  I like to pick and choose what I call :).  I don't use mixins, so I can't comment on that situation :)

Comment: So the way I fixed my bulkier code was to not include a constructor so it just inherited the constructor... I think that's pretty lame, but I'm just happy my code works now.

Comment: mgilson you know how to choose and what to call, but unfortunately you are not always the writer of the class. Sometimes the calling order matters(in multi-inheritance), so you just exposed yourself to a possible bug. Plus you'll have to keep up with any super class name changes. Both approaches are valid, but still, it warrants investigation on *both* occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about the self:

```
# pymyClass.py
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self,aList=None):
        if aList is not None:
            self.myList = aList
        else:
            self.myList = ['','','','','']

    def reset(self,aList=None):
        if aList is not None:
            self.myList = aList
        else:
            self.myList = ['','','','','']
```

without this mylist is "destroyed" after the if clause.